# Is it possible for one AWS ALB to steal a request intended for another ALB in the same vpc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I had a single ALB in a VPC which routed requests coming to different subdomains to different internal IP's of EC2 instances in the VPC. Route53 table looked something like this:

```
subdomain1.example.com -> 10.x.x.x

subdomain2.example.com -> 10.x.x.y
```

etc.

It also redirects every request coming to an unknown subdomain to the root domain, e.g. when you go to an address which didn't exist in Route53 like `qwert.example.com` it would get redirected to `example.com`

Now I added a Kubernetes cluster in the same VPC. I set up ALB ingress controller and deployed a service and an ingress, afaik their configuration seems to be correct.

I also created a Route53 entry which points another subdomain to the DNS name of the ALB managed by the ingress controller:

```
special.example.com -> somethingkubernetes.internal.blabla
```

But when I go to `special.example.com` it still gets redirected to `example.com`, like the first ALB is handling the request.

Is it possible that the first ALB to catch and handle the request intended for the kubernetes ALB?

Or somehow my ingress/ALB controller configuration is wrong and it cannot access `somethingkubernetes.internal.blabla` which in turn gets handled like an unknown subdomain, by getting redirected to `example.com` ?

Is there a way to debug/trace what is happening?

Edit: More info requested:

First ALB has a listener rule which is like:

| Name tag | Priority | Conditions | Actions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Default | Last (default) | If no other rule applies | Redirect to HTTPS://example.com:443/? Status code: HTTP_302 |

The first original ALB uses IP's to redirect. Second one uses alias records.